# How to Display Total number of Orders on a Certain Day in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to know how to display orders placed on a certain day.

For example:

I would like to display orders placed today.

My MySQL database contains the following tables:

1) orders
2) orders_statuses

Under **orders**, I have the following fields:
1) orders_id
2) orders_placed_date

Under **orders_statuses**, I have the following fields:
1) status_id
2) status_name

Whenever a new order is placed, it gets the default status_id = 3 (meaning status_name= Order is Pending)

So, if today 3 orders were placed, all of those will have the same status_id, which is 3. (Order is Pending)

Now, what query should I use to calculate orders placed today, and this week and this month?

Here is the query where I select all the orders placed in my cart:

```
SELECT   order_id, order_placed_date FROM  orders
```

The Result of the above query:

**Order ID  ----    Order Date Placed**
1 ---   12/30/2008 12:06:24 AM
2 ---   2/3/2009 1:57:17 AM
3 ---   2/3/2009 1:58:27 AM
4 ---   5/3/2009 1:58:48 AM
5 ---   6/3/2009 2:00:31 AM
6 ---   7/3/2009 2:01:47 AM
7 ---   7/3/2009 2:02:31 AM
9 ---   7/4/2009 2:21:18 PM
10 ---  7/4/2009 2:21:36 PM
11 ---  7/4/2009 2:22:18 PM
12 ---  7/4/2009 2:23:29 PM
13 ---  7/4/2009 2:24:24 PM

What I would like is to get the total number of orders placed today.

Since today's date is 4 July 2009, you can see from the above result that there are 5 orders placed on 4th July.

What query should I use to get the total number of orders in a certain day, in today's case, 5.

**UPDATE : Solved**

I used both Adam's and colithium querys to get the answer:

Here is what I used:

---

```
SELECT   COUNT(order_placed_date)
FROM     va_orders
WHERE    DATE(order_placed_date) = curdate();
```

---

It worked great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a foreign key in `ORDERS_STATUSES` called `ORDERS_ID`:

```
select o.orders_id
       , o.orders_placed_date
from   orders o
       inner join orders_statuses os
       os.orders_id = o.orders_id
    and
       os.status_id = 3
where  date(o.orders_placed_date) = curdate()
```

Comment: order_statuses does not have a foriegn key which links to orders_id in orders table.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of orders on a certain day:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders WHERE order_placed_date = @DayYouWant
```

To get the orders from today/this week/this month:

```
SELECT order_id, order_placed_date FROM orders WHERE order_placed_date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

If you want only orders with a status of 3 you will need to JOIN with the status table and add that criteria to the WHERE clause.